# Select within a Select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains all active withholding codes for each employee.  We have over 4000 employees, so each employee can have over 20 rows in this one table; one row for every withholding code they have.

I am looking to write a query where I only retrieve the employees from the table where they DO NOT have a specific withholding code. But since all the other withholding codes for that employee are also in the table, the query is pulling in those records (since they don't equal the withholding code I'm searching for). So for instance, the initial query I wrote looked something like below...

```
select a.employeename, b.employeenumber
from employeetable a
join positiontable b on b.employeeid = a.employeeid
    and b.positiontype = 'P'
    and b.expire is null
join empstatus c on c.employeeid = a.employeeid
    and c.status = 'ACTIVE'
join employeewithholding d on d.employeeid = a.employeeid
    and withholdingid <> '300'
```

Using this query will still pull in all employees since each employee has withholding codes in the table that don't = 300.  What would be the best way for me to write this query? This query serves as an error report, so if there are no employees who are missing the 300 withholding code that is fine and the report will be blank, but if they are missing the code I need that employee to display from the results of the query.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results (in tabular form) to illustrate your problem.

Comment: You should really have a lookup table `WithholdingCode`

Comment: @DaleK I'd like the report to pull people like below:

employee name employee number
test,mike 1234
test,kim 2569
test,sarah 2478
test,ashley 6523
test,bob 4895
test,jim 6325
test,amy 9568
test,mary 9981

Instead the results lists every employee with their employee number.  Sorry, I don't know how to make this pretty where it shows up neatly...

Comment: You [edit] it into the question and use the question formatting options :)

Comment: You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to get from a tab-separated list to formatted text. When pasting this into your request, use the `{}` button for code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with `NOT EXISTS` and a subquery

```sql
select a.employeename, b.employeenumber
from employeetable a
join positiontable b on b.employeeid = a.employeeid and b.positiontype = 'P' and b.expire is null
join empstatus c on c.employeeid = a.employeeid and c.status = 'ACTIVE'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM employeewithholding d WHERE d.employeeid = a.employeeid and withholdingid <> '300'
)
```

Comment: Thank you; I'm going to try this and see if it works.

Comment: This certainly helped me figure out how to modify it to retrieve the correct employees.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. From your query I take it that this is what you are after:

```
select employeename, employeenumber
from employeetable
where employeeid in
( 
  select employeeid
  from positiontable
  where positiontype = 'P'
  and expire is null
)
and employeeid in
(
  select employeeid 
  from empstatus
  where status = 'ACTIVE'
)
and employeeid not in
(
  select employeeid
  from employeewithholding
  where withholdingid = 300
);
```

You see, there is no need for a join here. You want to select data from the employee table, so `SELECT FROM employeetable`. You want to add criteria, so place it in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have started down this path, you can use `left join` and `where`:

```
select e.employeename, p.employeenumber
from employeetable e join
     positiontable p
     on p.employeeid = e.employeeid and
        p.positiontype = 'P' and
        p.expire is nulljoin
        empstatus s
        on s.employeeid = e.employeeid and
           s.status = 'ACTIVE' join
        employeewithholding ew
        on ew.employeeid = e.employeeid and
           ew.withholdingid = '300'
where ew.employeeid is null;
```

Note that meaningful table aliases make the query much, much easier to understand.